# C++ Referencing inside a polymorphic object

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have two classes

```
class A { C* c; }

class B { D* d; }
```

and find I need to construct a std::vector whose elements are either A or B (with the sequence decided at run time. So I constructed a polymorphic

```
class Poly {
    int   oType;
    void* oPtr;
}
```

as well as constructor

```
Poly::Poly(int type)
{
    if (type == 1) oPtr = new (A*) oPtr();
    if (type == 2) oPtr = new (B*) oPtr();
    oType = type;
}
```

along with a similarly structured destructor. Now

```
std::vector<Poly*> test;
```

works. However, I am having trouble accessing the subobjects.

I tried

```
if (test->oType == 1) test->oPtr->a;

if (test->oType == 1) test->(A*)oPtr->a;

if (test->oType == 1) (A*)(test->oPtr)->a;
```

all giving me the compiler error:

'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type

How do I convince the compiler that it's OK to reference a, if I know that the type of oPtr is A*?

Comment: `if (test->oType == 1) ((A*)test->oPtr)->c`

Comment: Why do you use `vector<Poly *>` and not `vector<Poly>`?

Comment: In C++ polymorphism is usually expressed by inheriting from a common base class. Then, it is usual to try to solve the "object type selection" problem using virtual methods rather than traditional "if/then" constructs.

Comment: @nwp this looks like a reduced version of the problem, it's probably a polymorphic object and the user wants to avoid object slicing. Also, you shouldn't be encouraging C style casts in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I convince the compiler that it's OK to reference a, if I know
>   that the type of oPtr is A*?

Strictly I think the answer to that is: `((A*)(test->oPtr))->a`. The better way to do that in C++ uses the cast operator: `static_cast<A*>(test->oPtr)->a`

**HOWEVER** This is not typically how this problem is addressed in c++. So I have provided a more usual approach that you may find useful:

```
class Poly
{
public:
    virtual ~Poly() {}
    virtual void do_something() = 0; // each sub-type has its own version of this
};

class A: public Poly
{
public:
    void do_something() /* override */ // c++11 only
    {
        std::cout << "Doing something A specific\n";
    }
};

class B: public Poly
{
public:
    void do_something() /* override */ // c++11 only
    {
        std::cout << "Doing something B specific\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Poly*> polys;

    // create data structure
    polys.push_back(new A);
    polys.push_back(new A);
    polys.push_back(new B);
    polys.push_back(new A);

    // use objects polymorphically
    for(size_t i = 0; i < polys.size(); ++i)
        polys[i]->do_something();

    // clean up memory (consider using 'smart pointers')
    for(size_t i = 0; i < polys.size(); ++i)
        delete polys[i];
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `static_cast<A*>(test->oPtr)->a` be better?

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, the polymorphic way is to use virtual functions.

Here is an implementation using smart pointers.  The creator class is responsible for creating the Poly object we are asking for.  This isolates the creation to one class.

Note that there are more sophisticated ways of doing this.  The goal here is to show, more or less, how it would be done using C++.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Poly 
{   
    public:
        virtual void Test() = 0; 
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<Poly> PolyPtr;

class A : public Poly
{
    public:
        void Test() { std::cout << "Test for A" << "\n"; }
};

class B : public Poly
{
    public:
        void Test() { std::cout << "Test for B" << "\n"; }
};

class PolyCreator
{
    public:
        PolyPtr CreatePolyObject(int oType)
        {
            switch( oType )
            {
                case 1: 
                    return PolyPtr(new A());
                case 2: 
                    return PolyPtr(new B());
            }
            throw "Could not find type in list";
        }
 };

 int main()
 {
     PolyCreator pCreator;
     std::vector<PolyPtr> PolyPtrVect;

     // create objects
     PolyPtrVect.push_back(pCreator.CreatePolyObject(1));
     PolyPtrVect.push_back(pCreator.CreatePolyObject(2));

     // call Test functions for each
     std::vector<PolyPtr>::iterator it = PolyPtrVect.begin();
     while ( it != PolyPtrVect.end())
     {
         (*it)->Test();
         ++it;
     }
 }
```

Output:

```
Test for A
Test for B
```

Note

1. There is only one `if()` statement that is isolated to the PolyCreator class.
2. There are no memory leaks due to usage of `std::unique_ptr`.
3. `Poly` is an abstract class.  All derived classes must implement the `Test` function.